# How do I automatically execute a button in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm coding in react native and I want a button to automatically clicked and the function to be executed when a user is on my app. I want the webbrowser to automatically open up when a user opens my app. My code so far is:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default function App() {
  const [result, setResult] = useState(null);
  
  const _handlePressButtonAsync = async () => {
    let result = await WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync('https://vitech-104517.square.site/');
    setResult(result);
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title="Open WebBrowser" onPress={_handlePressButtonAsync} />
      <Text>{result && JSON.stringify(result)}</Text>
      
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
});
```

The button "Open Webbrowser" needs to automatically be executed everytime a user is on my app. I want to do this by calling the function in react native. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
// Note the additional import of useEffect
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default function App() {
  const [result, setResult] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    _handlePressButtonAsync();
    // by adding the empty brackets below this code will only run once
  }, []);
  
  const _handlePressButtonAsync = async () => {
    let result = await WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync('https://vitech-104517.square.site/');
    setResult(result);
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title="Open WebBrowser" onPress={_handlePressButtonAsync} />
      <Text>{result && JSON.stringify(result)}</Text>
      
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
});
```

Comment: The useeffect line has a formatting error. It's saying declaration or statement expected.

Comment: It was looking for the ; which I just edited/added.

Comment: Its because `), []};` should be `}, []);`